# Alert a Slider Output

Tags: javascript, html

I have the slider that follows:

```js
var rangeValue;

localStorage.getItem('chanceoflive');
var chanceoflive = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("chanceoflive"));
var inputElement = document.querySelector('.range-input');
var submitElement = document.querySelector('.submit');
var x = 2;

submitElement.addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById('paragraph').innerHTML = chanceoflive;
  localStorage.setItem("chanceoflive", chanceoflive);
});

inputElement.addEventListener('change', function() {
  var rangeValue = parseInt(this.value);
  chanceoflive = chanceoflive || 0;


    if (rangeValue < 51 && rangeValue >= 0) {
      chanceoflive += 4;
    }
        else if (rangeValue < 100 && rangeValue > 50) {
            chanceoflive += 2;
          }


  }
);

function handleClick(){
    alert(chanceoflive);
}
```

```html
  <p id="write"></p>

  <main>
    <form oninput="output.value = Math.round(range.valueAsNumber / 1)">
      <h2>
          Choose the Height of Your Building
        </h2>
      <div class="range">
        <input name="range" type="range" min="0" max="100" class="range-input">
        <div class="range-output">
          <output id="output" class="output" name="output" for="range">
            50
          </output>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </main>

    <a href="chooselength.html"><button type="button" onclick="handleClick()" class="submit">Submit</button></a>
```

Basically, when you slide the slider to a number above 50, it outputs 2 with `localStorage`. When you slide it to a number that's 50 or below, it outputs 4 with `localStorage`.

Although, if you slide the slider to a number above 50 and then to a number 50 and below, it outputs 6, since it adds 2 and 4. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+=` assignments add the given number to the variable. If you don't want such addition, but want a plain assignment, then don't use `+=`, but just `=`. So change this:

```
if (rangeValue < 51 && rangeValue >= 0) {
    chanceoflive += 4;
}
else if (rangeValue < 100 && rangeValue > 50) {
    chanceoflive += 2;
}
```

To this:

```
if (rangeValue < 51 && rangeValue >= 0) {
    chanceoflive = 4;
}
else if (rangeValue < 100 && rangeValue > 50) {
    chanceoflive = 2;
}
```

Note that there is a problem for value 100, for which you do not have a value. You'd probably want that `< 100` to be changed to `<= 100`. Or, you can even remove that condition, since `rangeValue` cannot really get a value outside of the range `0...100`.

So you could correct and shorten the above to:

```
changeoflive = rangeValue > 50 ? 2 : 4;
```

Comment: I have multiple pages that will effect chanceoflive, hence localStorage, so I can't put equal signs

Comment: Would it work if I set different variables for each page and added them up at the end?

Comment: You did not explain this nuance in your question, but it is best to let each page store in its *own* `localStorage` variable, not touching the one used by another page. Then when you need the final result, you read out all those `localStorage` variables and make the final calculation based on them. Make sure to clear all these variables when you restart the whole navigation from scratch.

Comment: var chanceoflive1 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("chanceoflive1"));
  var chanceoflive2 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("chanceoflive2"));
  var chanceoflive3 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("chanceoflive3"));
  var chanceoflive4 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("chanceoflive4"));

document.getElementById('print4').innerHTML = chanceoflive1 += chanceoflive2 += chanceoflive3 += chanceoflive4;

Comment: Just use `+`, not `+=`. But then it would work. Note that you can just prefix with `+` to convert to numeric. Like this: `var chanceoflive1 = +localStorage.getItem("chanceoflive1");`

Comment: It just prints `NaN`

Comment: Then see first what each individual `localStorage.getItem` returns without converting to numeric. You must be sure they contain numbers. All of them. If you want to deal with cases where some of them might not have been defined, then do at the end `...innerHTML = (chanceoflive1 || 0) + (chanceoflive2 || 0) + (chanceoflive3 || 0) + (chanceoflive4 || 0);`

Comment: All of them indivudually alert a number, but it still prints `NaN` at the end.

Comment: Do you mean I should remove `parseint()` for each one?

Comment: No, I don't mean that. I mean you should make sure those localStorage variables have numeric content. This you can do by a separate line with `console.log(localStorage.getItem('changeoflive1`));` ...etc. Just for debugging. The `NaN` output means one of them was not numeric, ... probably undefined.

Comment: It just says null. This is what I did -

Comment: `console.log(localStorage.getItem('changeoflive1'));
console.log(localStorage.getItem('changeoflive2'));
console.log(localStorage.getItem('changeoflive3'));
console.log(localStorage.getItem('changeoflive4'));
var chanceoflive1 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("chanceoflive1"));
var chanceoflive2 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("chanceoflive2"));
var chanceoflive3 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("chanceoflive3"));
var chanceoflive4 = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("chanceoflive4"));`

Comment: So? That means you did not store any value in those localStorage items yet. We can talk for ages about this, but it is really not that difficult. If you don't put anything in it, you don't get anything out of it. Above I gave you a solution on how you can deal with these cases (if you really want to make it work without putting anything in those). Use `|| 0` at the right place.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I took too long.

Comment: Sorry, but do I put the `|| 0` at the end of the document.getElementById, or at the localStorage?

Comment: In the line where you assign to `innerHTML`. I wrote it in one of my previous comments.

Comment: Is that in the page where I have `console.log`?

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH